# How to Check Multiple File Present In folder We save Or Not If Any Missing Then Abort Script

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I save Files In my file folder like adb.exe, fastboot.exe And some scripts like reboot-bootloader.bat and many more. I want to zip them but I want to sure before zip them, all files are present or not if anyone missing then zip task abort.

but it is not possible to write all of them in each and every single line.
I'm looking for something one command like just put files name on that command that check and tell which file missing if not missing then run my zip command.

I'm try if statement like this:-

if exist <.\files\filename.*> (
echo file present.
) else (
echo file is missing.
)

Comment: `for %%a in (adb.exe fastboot.exe reboot-bootloader.bat "spaces in filename.ext") do ...`

Comment: `for %%a in (adb.exe fastboot.exe reboot-bootloader.bat hmTu.txt) do echo file present.`
i put  adb.exe fastboot.exe and run this code it shows e files is present 4 times but i have only two files present in folder. im also konw missing file so when i m zip my folder all filese must be presented that movement.


im write a code by myself using if else loop but that is too much lengthy and hard. 


`@echo off
echo checking file structure...
if exist "adb.exe" (
echo adb.exe is Presents.
) else ( 
echo adb.exe is Not Presents.
)`

if im do same for all file its too much painful.

Comment: `for %%a in ... do if exist "%%~a" (echo %%~a exists) else (echo %%~a missing`)